# Not able to connect two user inputs

Tags: java

As a beginner of programming, I'm trying to write a simple **Java** program for comparing the prices (lowest and highest price) of some items entered by the user.

So far, I've managed to write the code telling the user which price is the lowest and highest, but I'm not able to inform the user which item the price refers to. Any ideas?

```
System.out.println("\nEnter the name of item 1 ");
String itemOne = scanner.next();
System.out.println("\nEnter the price of " + itemOne + ": ");
double priceItemOne = scanner.nextDouble();

System.out.println("\nEnter the name of item 2 ");
String itemTwo = scanner.next();
System.out.println("\nEnter the price of " + itemTwo + ": ");
double priceItemTwo = scanner.nextDouble();

double highest = Math.max(priceItemOne, priceItemTwo);
System.out.println("\nThe most expensive item is " + highest);
double lowest = Math.min(priceItemOne, priceItemTwo);
System.out.println("\nThe cheapest item is " + lowest);
```

Comment: The Object Oriented way to do this would be to have some sort of `Item` class with `name` and `price` as fields, with their getters and setters. Otherwise, with your current approach, you can, for example, compare `highest` with `priceItemOne`. If they are equal, the item with the highest price is `itemOne`. Otherwise, it's `itemTwo`.

Comment: Create three indexes. ``int index = 0, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 0;`` Now, when you find a new value that goes in highest, then set maxIndex to the current index. Likewise with lowest and minIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only idea is to learn more about Java (and OOP), this solution may be a quick starter for you, have a look.

```
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;
    
    public class Question63869241 {
    
        static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            // pass 1, 10 for taking 10 item inputs from user
            List<Item> items = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,2)
                    .mapToObj(Question63869241::getItemInputFromUser)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
            Item expensiveItem = getMostExpensiveItem(items);
            Item cheapestItem = getCheapestItem(items);
    
            System.out.println("\nThe most expensive item '" + expensiveItem.getItemName()
                    + "' is priced at: " + expensiveItem.getPrice()  );
            System.out.println("\nThe cheapest item '" + cheapestItem.getItemName()
                    + "' is priced at: " + cheapestItem.getPrice() );
        }
    
        private static Item getItemInputFromUser(int sequence){
            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of item " + sequence);
            String name = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("\nEnter the price of '" + name + "': ");
            double price = scanner.nextDouble();
            return new Item(name, price);
        }
    
        private static Item getMostExpensiveItem(List<Item> items){
            return items.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::getPrice).reversed())
                    .findFirst().get();
        }
    
        private static Item getCheapestItem(List<Item> items){
            return items.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::getPrice))
                    .findFirst().get();
        }
    
    
    }
    
    
    class Item {
    
        private String itemName;
        private Double price;
    
        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }
    
        public void setItemName(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }
    
        public Double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    
        public void setPrice(Double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    
        public Item(String itemName, Double price) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.price = price;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Your example is way more structured than my code, you're right to say that I need the hit the books in order gain further knowledge.. And I definitely will.

I have a question about the range of items user is allowed to enter. 

I'm currently using the "if" and "else" statements to ask the user how many items to compare. This works, but let's say that I want to let the user decide how many items to compare, without having to ask how many. 

Would that be possible? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: The above answer is entirely based on your question description AND DOES NOT/SHOULD NOT cover any additional requirement changes. As per your comment, it looks like you wanted to solve one problem and now asking for some other problem. If so, please ask, a separate question, if not, please post your all queries at once in your question (not by editing multiple times :-) or in comments). That's not the way SO community works :)

Comment: The second question was something that crossed my mind after posting the first one, I'm used to communities not allowing posting multiple questions when it can be discussed in the same thread. Any way, good to know how SO works, I'll post a new question next time. Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.print("Enter the name of item 1: ");
String oneName = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the price of item 1: ");
double onePrice = scan.nextDouble();

scan.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter the name of item 2: ");
String twoName = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the price of item 2: ");
double twoPrice = scan.nextDouble();

int compare = Double.compare(onePrice, twoPrice);

if (compare == 0)
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Both prices for item 1 (%s) and item 2 (%s) are equal: %.2f\n", oneName, twoName, onePrice);
else if (compare > 0) {
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "The most expensive item is 1 (%s): %.2f\n", oneName, onePrice);
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "The cheapest item is 2 (%s): %.2f\n", twoName, twoPrice);
} else {
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "The most expensive item is 2 (%s): %.2f\n", twoName, twoPrice);
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "The cheapest item is 1 (%s): %.2f\n", oneName, onePrice);
}
```